# How to measure the impact of an edge change to the graph status change

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request

**Problem definition**: Given a sequence of **undirected weighted** graphs $\mathcal{G} = \{G^1, G^2, \dots, G^n\}$.  For each graph $G^i \in \mathcal{G}$ can be denoted as $G_i = (V, E^i)$, where $V$ is a set of vertices and $|V|$ is the number of vertices.  $E^i \in \mathbb{R}^{|V|\times|V|}$ is a set of edges. $E^i = [w^i_{u,v}], u,v \in V$, in which $w^i_{u,v} \ge 0$ is the a nonnegative number represent the weight of edge joining vertex $u$ and vertex $v$. $w^i_{u, v} = 0$ represents $u$ and $v$ are not joined. And there is a state evaluation function $S(G^i)$ (e.g. community division function, structural stability, clustering) for each $G^i \in \mathcal{G}$ (for convenient $S(\mathcal{G})=\{S(G^1), S(G^2),\dots,S(G^n)\}$) . There is also a function $\delta(\mathcal{G})$ to indicate the state of $G^1$ and $G^n$ is same or not (0 for same, $S(G^n) - S(G^1)$ for others).  Now for a sequence graphs $\mathcal{G}$ with $\delta(\mathcal{G}) \ne 0$, we want to evaluate the influence of the changes of edge $(u,v)$ in two adjacent graphs on $\delta(\mathcal{G})$. In other words, we need such a function[^2] $f \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ :
$$
f(w^i_{u,v},w^{i+1}_{u,v}|\delta(\mathcal{G}), S(\mathcal{G}), \mathcal{G}) \quad \text{where} \quad 1 \le i \le n-1 \quad \text{and} \quad \delta(\mathcal{G}) \ne 0
$$
We specialize the problem with $|\mathcal{G^*}|=2$ , then $\mathcal{G^*} = \{G^1, G^2 \}$ , and $f$ can be represented as:
$$
f(w^1_{u,v},w^2_{u,v}|\delta(\mathcal{G^*}), S(\mathcal{G^*}), \mathcal{G^*}) \quad \delta(\mathcal{G}) \ne 0
$$

The following is an example:
[image]
In this example, $S$ is a community detection function.

In $G^1$, there are 3 communities [1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7] and [8, 9, 10].
In $G^2$, there are 2 communities [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] and [8, 9, 10]
This community structure change is mainly caused by (4, 5). (While the connectivity of (2, 9) is higher than (4, 5), (2,9) does not change the community structure.) So (4, 5) should get a high score, (2, 9) get a low score.

HELP WANTED:
Can you recommend some related references?